# determine if the index changed of a listview is triggered by mouse or keyboard

Tags: vb.net, winforms, listview

how can I determine if the index changed of a listview is triggered by using mouse or keyboard?

to determine a selected index changed event, I use this

```
Private Sub lv_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles lv.SelectedIndexChanged

End Sub
```

is there an event where it is only for mouse click? or any condition to detect if it is triggered by a mouse click or by keyboard? please help

Comment: This is fairly unwise.  But it is doable, use the ListView.MouseDown and PreviewKeyDown events to set a Boolean variable that you can test in your SelectedIndexChanged event handler.  Test carefully.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you can check the MouseButtons property of the Sender (ListView) to determine if the user is pressing any mouse buttons:

```
Private Sub lv_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles lv.SelectedIndexChanged
    If sender.MouseButtons = MouseButtons.None Then
        ' No buttons being pressed (keyboard used)
    Else
        ' Mouse button being pressed
    End If
End Sub
```